# Copy from div into a new iframe

Tags: javascript, iframe

Ultimately I’m trying out a technique for printing a specific `div`, but I’m bogging down on this part of the problem.

I have some code which is supposed to copy from a `div` to a new `iframe`:

```js
var iframe = document.createElement('iframe');
var div = document.querySelector('div#sidebar');
var content = div.innerHTML;
iframe.srcdoc = `<!DOCTYPE html><html><head></head><body>${content}</body></html>`;

document.body.append(iframe);

iframe.contentWindow.print();
```

I’ve tried this in the developer tools on one of the SO pages (there was a `div#sidebar` I could try it with).

I notice that I need to add the `iframe` to the document to get this to work at all. Otherwise the `.contentWindow` property is `null`.

The code seems to work to some extent, but the `iframe` is empty, or so it seems. What ends up being printed is nothing.

What’s the trick in creating a new `iframe` with copoied contents?

Comment: @traktor I get no such error on Firefox (macOS). I have already searched all over the web for the solution. Most solutions are pretty old and involve creating a new window and using `document.write()` to create new content. As I said, `iframe.contentWindow.print()` does something, but it seems to be an empty `iframe`.

Comment: Glad you've solved it - I'll delete my earlier comment, and stop polishing a working solution to turn the print div into a modal with an opaque background :-)

Comment: @traktor Thanks. My question is now answered, but I’ve got a lot more work to do to make this practical. So far I’ve added some code to remove the `iframe` when finished, but it would be better if I didn’t have to add it to the document. I also need to find a way to copy the styles.

Answer (score 1):

OK, I have an answer. I should have known better, since I’ve just finished teaching on a similar subject.

The code works, but it runs too early. I need to wait for the document to finish loading.

Here is a working version:

```js
var iframe = document.createElement('iframe');
var div = document.querySelector('div#sidebar');
var content = div.innerHTML;
iframe.srcdoc = `<!DOCTYPE html><html><head></head><body>${content}</body></html>`;

document.body.append(iframe);

//  wait for iframe to finish loading:
    iframe.onload = () => {
        iframe.contentWindow.print();
        iframe.contentWindow.addEventListener('afterprint', event => {
            iframe.remove();
        });
    };
```

Answer (score 0):

For your reference here's the "modal" solution I referred to in comment. Altering the page title and restoring it after printing is optional and can easily be omitted. If omitted the modal declarations could possibly be included in an `@media print` CSS rule depending on page functionality but I haven't pursued it.

```js
"use strict";

document.querySelector("#buttonId").addEventListener("click", event=> {
  const printDiv = document.querySelector("#divId");
  const pageTitle = document.title;
  document.title = "Print of DIV";
  printDiv.classList.add("modal");
  print();
  printDiv.classList.remove("modal");
  document.title = pageTitle;
});
```

```css
.modal {   /* assuming the modal element is NOT within a positioned element */
   position: absolute;
   min-width: 100%;
   min-height: calc(100% - 3px);
   background-color: white;
   break-after: avoid;

}
```

```html
<div id="divId">Hello folks and world</div>

<button type="button" id="buttonId">Print</button>


<p> and some page content that shouldn't be printed</p>
```